# How can I know which operation can not be placed on GPU in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

How can I know which operation can not be placed on GPU in tensorflow? Is there a place that I can check?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check kernels (i.e. implementations on devices) for ops which are located at this directory: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/r0.11/tensorflow/core/kernels/

For example, suppose you would like to know whether `softmax` can be placed on GPU. You can navigate to the kernel of `softmax`: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.11/tensorflow/core/kernels/softmax_op.cc. You will find the following code:

```
REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER(
    Name("Softmax").Device(DEVICE_GPU).TypeConstraint<Eigen::half>("T"),
    SoftmaxOp<GPUDevice, Eigen::half>);
```

This means there is a kernel for `softmax` on GPU with type `float16`. The prerequisite is that you have to build your tensorflow with GPU enabled.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's really helpful!

Comment: In some kernel, I saw something like [#define REGISTER_GPU_KERNELS(type)](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/e7508b6efd51f7cfed32ff277e805f8ea60a7a48/tensorflow/core/kernels/variable_ops.cc). How do I know which types are enabled?

Comment: Under that, there is a macro `TF_CALL_GPU_NUMBER_TYPES`, search for that in the repo, you'll find [this page](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/framework/register_types.h#L162). It indicates `TF_CALL_GPU_NUMBER_TYPES` will register the kernel for type `float16`, `float32` and `double`.